# Python dataframe replace last n rows with a list of n elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame of 2500 rows. I am trying to replace last n rows a dataframe with a list of n elements. I am giving an example of my problem and what I wanted

```
df = 
      A
0    10.5
1    10.5
2    10.5
3    10.5
4    10.5
5    10.5
6    10.5
```

My new list has two elements to be placed at the bottom two rows.

```
op_res = [20.5, 30.5]
```

My code and present output:

```
df.loc[-2:,'A'] = pd.Series(op_res)
df = 
      A
0    10.5
1    10.5
2    10.5
3    10.5
4    10.5
5    nan
6    nan
```

What could be wrong in my code? 
My code and present output:

```
df = 
      A
0    10.5
1    10.5
2    10.5
3    10.5
4    10.5
5    20.5
6    30.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.A.to_numpy()[-2:]=op_res
df
      A
0  10.5
1  10.5
2  10.5
3  10.5
4  10.5
5  20.5
6  30.5
```

The problem in your code: index not match, so when assign it back, it will return nan, since pandas assign will match index as always

```
pd.Series(op_res)
0    20.5
1    30.5
dtype: float64
```

Index from original df

```
df.iloc[-2:,0] 
5    10.5
6    10.5
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

From above, we know the index [0,1] can not match with index [5,6] so all assign value will return `nan`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `DataFrame.iloc` and broadcast the list to an array with `numpy.array`:

```
df.iloc[-len(op_res):] = np.array(op_res)[:, None]


      A
0  10.5
1  10.5
2  10.5
3  10.5
4  10.5
5  20.5
6  30.5
```

Or with `DataFrame.append`:

```
df.iloc[:-len(op_res)].append(pd.DataFrame({'A': op_res}), ignore_index=True)

      A
0  10.5
1  10.5
2  10.5
3  10.5
4  10.5
5  20.5
6  30.5
```

Comment: I tried this `df1['v'].iloc[-len(a1):] = np.array(a1)[:, None]
`. Got following error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1802,1) into shape (1802)`

Comment: remove the `[:, None]`